# CocoaPods: supporting binary xcframework dependencies like SPM's `binaryTarget`

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have a library using Swift Package Manger (SPM) but I need to support CocoaPods and I'm getting stuck figuring out how to support a binary xcframework dependency. SPM allows hosting a binary xcframework like the following `Package.swift` example below.

How can I do this with CocoaPods?

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyTarget"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyTarget",
            dependencies: ["BinaryTarget"],
            path: "Sources/"
        ),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "BinaryTarget",
            url: "https://someplace.com/public/BinaryTarget.xcframework.zip",
            checksum: "123abcxyz"
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: With cocapods you won't be able to use a zipped framework. However, binary frameworks are used in many libraries, see for example the Appcenter SDK for iOS: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple/blob/develop/AppCenter.podspec

Answer (score -1):

See the `vendored_frameworks` attribute in the [podspec docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks) and this [example](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json).